# Is this effective divisor $E$ linearly equivalent to zero?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, divisors-algebraic-geometry

Let $E$ be an effective divisor such that $E \cdot E=0$. If $-E$ is linearly equivalent to an effective divisor, can I say that $E$ is linearly equivalent to $0$? Or are there any counterexamples?

Comment: That's right. The only line bundle $L$ on a scheme $X$ such that $L$ and $L^\vee$ both have global sections is $L \cong \mathcal O_X$.

Comment: @TabesBridges It is not quite true on schemes, so good to clarify.